# Use of Teleport instead of SSH

Tags: ssh

From a security standpoint is it safe to run [Teleport](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport) instead of an SSH daemon?

Comment: The reasons why are outlined on their Readme. As for a security review, we can't really do that.

Comment: @drewbenn Sorry for asking without doing enough research.

Answer (score 5):

For anything really sensitive, it's hard to justify using Teleport given how young it is.

OpenSSH is battle-tested and has had 10000's of developer hours spent on it, as well as countless audits.

OpenSSH is also guaranteed to be around for a long time to come.

Comment: OpenSSH being "battle-tested" isn't as structurally sound given how many CVEs have been cropping up for it lately. But I do agree 100%.

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson - I guess that is side effect of more work being done on it.  If you looks at the [CVE list](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/openssl) you see more CVEs in 2015 and 2016 but also a bigger number of openssl versions (1.0.0x, 1.0.1x, and now 1.0.2x).  The versions (and the number of lines of code) are going up quicker than ever before.

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson: that's the result of being battle-tested. I really doubt Teleport authors write significantly more secure code than OpenSSH authors.

Comment: Being older means OpenSSH has had more testing; it also means it has much more accumulated cruft that could be vulnerable.